# Extracting vector data from a VTK(vtu) file using Python for each cell,

Tags: python, xml, vtk, paraview

I have a large number (~200) of VTK(VTU) XML files containing some vector data as components along X,Y and  Z direction. It is in some **base64** encoding. I'm trying to write a simple python code to read these VTU(xml) files one by one and extract the vector information, and to store it in some form. I'm new to programming, I searched a lot but can't find any tutorials or documentations regarding this. Can anyone help me by suggesting a way to extract a particular Vector information from a VTU file?  My VTU file looks like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt32" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <FieldData>
      <DataArray type="Float64" Name="timeInPs" NumberOfTuples="1" format="appended" RangeMin="3830100.0073"         RangeMax="3830100.0073"         offset="0"                   />
    </FieldData>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="611"                  NumberOfCells="2379"                >
      <PointData Scalars="Material" Vectors="Magnetization">
        <DataArray type="Float64" Name="Magnetization" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="1"                    RangeMax="1"                    offset="48"                  />
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="Material" format="appended" RangeMin="0"                    RangeMax="0"                    offset="16484"               />
      </PointData>
      <CellData>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" RangeMin="1.6616296724e-15"     RangeMax="5.000000259"          offset="16544"               >
          <InformationKey name="L2_NORM_RANGE" location="vtkDataArray" length="2">
            <Value index="0">
              1.6616296724e-15
            </Value>
            <Value index="1">
              5.000000259
            </Value>
          </InformationKey>
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="23988"               />
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="46064"               />
        <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" format="appended" RangeMin=""                     RangeMax=""                     offset="50312"               />
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
  <AppendedData encoding="base64">
   _AQAAAACAAAAIAAAAEAAAAA==eJzT2fGWYZWFryMAECkDQg==AQAAAACAAABIOQAAFTAAAA==eJwtm3k81N/D6TM==eJzj4hoFo2AUjIJRMApGwSgYBWQCABzvXO8=
  </AppendedData>
</VTKFile>
```

Comment: Are you using VTK or ParaView ?

Comment: I use Paraview to visualize the VTU files.

Comment: then why do you need a python script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [VTKExamples](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/IO/ReadUnstructuredGrid/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# by Panos Mavrogiorgos, email: pmav99 <> gmail

import vtk.vtk

# The source file
file_name = "path/to/your/file.vtu"

# Read the source file.
reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(file_name)
reader.Update()  # Needed because of GetScalarRange
output = reader.GetOutput()
scalar_range = output.GetScalarRange()

# Create the mapper that corresponds the objects of the vtk.vtk file
# into graphics elements
mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
mapper.SetInputData(output)
mapper.SetScalarRange(scalar_range)

# Create the Actor
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# Create the Renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)  # Set background to white

# Create the RendererWindow
renderer_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderer_window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Create the RendererWindowInteractor and display the vtk_file
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderer_window)
interactor.Initialize()
interactor.Start()
```

Comment: Thanks...  One more small problem, the VTU file also contains information about "time" _(please see the 4th line in the VTU file)_. Unlike field data, this information is not associated with nodes or cells. How can we extract this information? (I'm using Paraview to visualize. But now using Python and cpp to extract information for further analysis)

Comment: See this example https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/Visualization/UnstructuredTransientVolumeRendering/ and use `SetUpdateTimeStep` method.

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't seem to be working. When I'm running this, I'm getting `0.1,0.2...` etc,  actually the time I should get is **7650** ps, this can be accessed using Paraview . _(here time is written not as time steps, but as a single value for the entire VTU file, as one VTU file represent the data at a particular instant i time.)_